# Pass an argument to a method via a call to another method. Is there a performance difference?

Tags: c#, performance, methods, memory-management

For example I can write next code

```
var key = ConvertToKey<TViewModel>();
var page = typeof(TView);
_ = _pages.TryAdd(key, page)
    ? true
    : throw new InvalidOperationException($"ViewModel already registered '{key}'");
```

Or like this

```
_ = _pages.TryAdd(ConvertToKey<TViewModel>(), typeof(TView))
    ? true
    : throw new InvalidOperationException($"ViewModel already registered '{ConvertToKey<TViewModel>()}'");
```

I'm interested in what the difference is in terms of runtime. Abstract from the above example with its simple return types. Let's imagine that there are 100 or 1000 similar methods. Which of the spellings is preferable for better performance? In the second case, after all, the result is also saved for passing on. But without explicitly creating a variable as in the first case.

Maybe this is just about readability? And in one case it is convenient to write one line, in another case to declare a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach will be slower in the exception case, because it calls `ConvertToKey` twice. Given that you're already in the "ouch, I'm throwing an exception" situation, that's unlikely to be significant.

Other than that, they should have the same execution time. I would definitely focus on readability here.

Comment: `I would definitely focus on readability` Are you only talking about this case? Or in general, about the choice between writing.

Comment: @Viewed: Well, *certainly* in this case - but in general I would always write the most readable code until I had *evidence* of a significant performance difference.